# NameError: name 'WD_COLOR_INDEX' is not defined while using python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, highlight, python-docx

I have been trying to find the highlight colors in an MS Word document using `python-docx` (python-docx-0.8.6, python 2.7, 32 bit) and process each piece of the text based on its highlight color.

Following the documentation, I tried to import/use `WD_COLOR_INDEX`, but can't seem to locate it.

```
from docx.enum import *

if (doc.paragraphs[i].runs[j].font.highlight_color == WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW): 
    #do the appropriate thing for the yellow-highlighted text
```

How do I import the color index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This enumeration is related to text, so is found in the `docx.enum.text` module:

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX
```

It also has an alias (for more compact expression), so you can use this instead:

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR
```

Which makes each reference shorter, e.g. `WD_COLOR.YELLOW`.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask a follow-up question: I am trying to associate a Part-of-Speech (POS) tag with the highlighted color of the text (the color actually encodes the type of the named entity) for each word/token. The POS tag is extracted using ,say, NLTK's POS tagger and the highlight (thankfully) is extracted using python-docx. The difficulty is that the tokenizer and tagger split the text differently from the run-wise split associated with the font+highlight, etc. What would be the best way to get the correspondence  (e.g., a tuple would be: <word/token, POS-tag, highlight-color>?

Comment: @HW It's really a separate question. If you post it and tag it with 'python-docx' I'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

***in python 3.7***

```
from docx.enum import *
from docx.enum.text import WD_COLOR_INDEX
if (doc.paragraphs[i].runs[j].font.highlight_color == WD_COLOR_INDEX.YELLOW): 
    #do the appropriate thing for the yellow-highlighted text
```